# Iterating through a dataframe to pull mins and max's as well as other columns based off of those values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to python and very new to pandas so any help would be appreciated!

I have a dataframe where the data is structured like below:

| Batch_Name | Tag 1 | Tag 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01 | 1 | 3 |
| 2019-02 | 2 | 3 |

I want to iterate through the dataframe and pull the following into a new dataframe:

The max value for each tag (there are 5 in my full data frame)

The batch name at that max value

The min value for that tag

The batch name at that min value

The average for that tag

The std for that tag

I have had a lot of trouble trying to mentally structure this, but I run into errors even trying to create the dataframe with the summary statistics. Below is my first attempt at creating a new method with the stats, I wasn't sure how to pull the batch names at all.

```
def tag_stats(df):
    min_col = {}
    min_col_batch = {}
    max_col = {}
    max_col_batch = {}
    std_col = {}
    avg_col = {}
    for col in range(df.shape[3:]):
        max_col[col]= df[col].max()
        min_col[col]= df[col].min()
        std_col[col]= df[col].std()
        avg_col[col]= df[col].avg()

    result = pd.DataFrame([min_col, max_col, std_col, avg_col], index=['min', 'max', 'std', 'avg'])
    return result
```

Comment: `df.agg([min, max, 'mean', 'std'])` or `df.describe()`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer based on your code!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Slightly modified your function
def tag_stats(df, tag_list):
    df = df.set_index('Batch_Name')
    
    data = {
        'tag':[],
        'min':[],
        'max':[],
        'min_batch':[],
        'max_batch':[],
        'std':[],
        'mean':[],
    }
    for tag in tag_list:
        values = df[tag]
        
        data['tag'].append(tag)
        data['min'].append(values.min())
        data['max'].append(values.max())
        data['min_batch'].append(values.idxmin())
        data['max_batch'].append(values.idxmax())
        data['std'].append(values.std())
        data['mean'].append(values.mean())

    result = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    return result


#Create a df using some random data
np.random.seed(1)

num_batches = 10

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Batch_Name':['batch_{}'.format(i) for i in range(num_batches)],
    'Tag 1':np.random.randint(1,100,num_batches),
    'Tag 2':np.random.randint(1,100,num_batches),
    'Tag 3':np.random.randint(1,100,num_batches),
    'Tag 4':np.random.randint(1,100,num_batches),
    'Tag 5':np.random.randint(1,100,num_batches),
})


#Apply your function
cols = ['Tag 1','Tag 2','Tag 3','Tag 4','Tag 5']
summary_df = tag_stats(df, cols)
print(summary_df)
```

Output

```
     tag  min  max min_batch max_batch        std  mean
0  Tag 1    2   80   batch_9   batch_6  32.200759  38.0
1  Tag 2    7   85   batch_2   batch_7  28.926919  39.9
2  Tag 3   14   97   batch_9   batch_7  33.297314  63.4
3  Tag 4    1   82   batch_7   batch_9  31.060693  37.1
4  Tag 5    4   89   batch_7   batch_1  31.212711  43.3
```

The comment for @It_is_Chris is great too, here is an answer based on it

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Create a df using some random data
np.random.seed(1)

num_batches = 10

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Batch_Name':['batch_{}'.format(i) for i in range(num_batches)],
    'Tag 1':np.random.randint(1,100,num_batches),
    'Tag 2':np.random.randint(1,100,num_batches),
    'Tag 3':np.random.randint(1,100,num_batches),
    'Tag 4':np.random.randint(1,100,num_batches),
    'Tag 5':np.random.randint(1,100,num_batches),
})

#Convert to a long df and index by Batch_Name:
#       index  |    tag   | tag_value
# ------------------------------------
#     batch_0  | Tag 1 38 |        38
#     batch_1  | Tag 1 13 |        13
#     batch_2  | Tag 1 73 |        73
long_df = df.melt(
    id_vars = 'Batch_Name',
    var_name = 'tag',
    value_name = 'tag_value',
).set_index('Batch_Name')

#Groupby tag and aggregate to get columns of interest
summary_df = long_df.groupby('tag').agg(
    max_value = ('tag_value','max'),
    max_batch = ('tag_value','idxmax'),
    min_value = ('tag_value','min'),
    min_batch = ('tag_value','idxmin'),
    mean_value = ('tag_value','mean'),
    std_value = ('tag_value','std'),
).reset_index()

summary_df
```

Output:

```
     tag  max_value max_batch  min_value min_batch  mean_value  std_value
0  Tag 1         80   batch_6          2   batch_9        38.0  32.200759
1  Tag 2         85   batch_7          7   batch_2        39.9  28.926919
2  Tag 3         97   batch_7         14   batch_9        63.4  33.297314
3  Tag 4         82   batch_9          1   batch_7        37.1  31.060693
4  Tag 5         89   batch_1          4   batch_7        43.3  31.212711
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but this gave me the below error:

TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Comment: Do you get that error if you copy and paste the code I wrote above, or is that an error from when you try to apply the code to your situation? Does your `df` have more columns than just `Batch_Name` and `Tag 1` `Tag 2` etc

Comment: I've edited the answer above to include an approach more similar to the code that you posted. maybe that will be easier to get working on your end